# How do I get back deleted podcast episodes to download again in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I've deleted and (that is, removed from disk) some old episodes of a podcast and I would like iTunes to forget that I every downloaded and deleted them.

How can I make them appear as un-downloaded (that is, grey with the "get" button showing) in iTunes again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try setting the auto-delete up to the most current date.  iTunes will do all the deleting on its own, and once again give you the option to download.

If you've already deleted them, you'll need to unsubscribe and resubscribe to get the full listing, since refreshing doesn't give you the full list if you manually delete episodes.

Comment: just tested this out. Indeed you have unsubscrieb and resubscribe. In my case i had to restart iTunes before updating podcasts would refresh!

Comment: Great. I had download error and some bad noise in my podcast, so first, I have deleted episode from disc. Then I have to delete episode in itunes, unsubscribe, subscribe and working - I could download it again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you unsubscribe from the podcast and then re-subscribe, you can re-download the episodes that you want.

I hope this helps.